# codeigniter - how to display a popup form in a div tag using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'd like have a button on my page that display a form (in a div) which includes text box and two buttons.
I'm not too familiar yet with jquery but I did do some reading and have tried to base my code on an example found here at: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

I have a button that looks like:

```
 <input type='button' class='btn btn-info' value='Change VLAN' id='changevlan'/>
```

and a div that contains the details of the pop form that I want:

```
 <div id="dialog-form" title="Change Vlan">
<p>You must supply a new vlan number</p>

<form>
<fieldset>
    <label for="vlan">Vlan Number:</label>
    <input type="text" name="vlan" id="vlan" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
</fieldset>
</form>
 </div>
```

And then at the bottom of my page, i have included the jquery and jquery ui libraries (I loaded at bottom for faster page loading) and I have the following javascript: (I based it off the example i mentioned at the beginning of this post.)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    // a workaround for a flaw in the demo system (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4375), ignore!
    $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

    var vlan = $( "#vlan" ),
      tips = $( ".validateTips" );

    function updateTips( t ) {
        tips
            .text( t )
            .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
        setTimeout(function() {
            tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
        }, 500 );
    }

    function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
        if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
            o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
            updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
                min + " and " + max + "." );
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
        if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
            o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
            updateTips( n );
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Change Vlan": function() {
                var bValid = true;
                allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

                bValid = bValid && checkLength( vlan, "vlan", 1, 1 );
                bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( vlan, /^([0-9])+$/i, "vlan must be numeric." );

                if ( bValid ) {
                    //this is where I need to redirect to another URL passing the vlan number.
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
        }
    });

    $( "#changevlan" )
        .button()
        .click(function() {
        alert('in here');
            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
});
</script>
```

As you can see I inserted an alert statement to ensure that i was getting into the javascript.  But I don't get the alert message.  And the contents of the div form just show up on the main page when it's initially rendered.

What I've checked so far:

I've tried to double check that the name of my button that should trigger the div form display matches the name of the variable i'm looking for in the javascript function:

```
    $( "#changevlan" )
        .button()
        .click(function() {
        alert('in here');
            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
```

I've also made sure that my div form is called #dialog-form

But I'm not too sure what else to try.  If you ahve any suggestions, I'd appreciate it. I also need to know how to access the contents of the text box and then redirect the user to a new controller and method, passing the vlan number as a parameter. 
Maybe I can just do a window.location type of thing...

Thanks.

Comment: Consider using [jQueryTools Overlays](http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/index.html)

Comment: I'm going to try to check out the web developer tools in firefox / F12 in IE when I get back to the office... but in the mean time, if you see anything obvious, i'm all ears. thanks.

Comment: Use colorbox insted. http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

u dont need more libraries, just make a simple jQueryUI .dialog, inside the "div" element for the dialog place some inline php from CI, something like `<div id="dlgPopUpForm"><?= $this->load->view('dialogView.php'); ?></div>`, then build your form in the `dialogView.php` of course.

At run time, the php wil be read into the div and the jquery options u use to create the dialog will handle the rest. something like `$("#dlgPopUpForm").dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true }); $("#someButton").click(function(e){ $("#dlgPopUpForm").dialog("open"); });`

dont forget to include your javascript for the form on the form view page (`dialogView.php` in my example)

maybe when i'm not so lazy, i'll make ya an example later today, though, its pretty straight forward